Controlled timed scrolling between widgets, each with their own time to be displayed
I am trying for a while to create a widget that can loop between different widgets on a timed basis, and each of the widgets can have its own time to be shown on the screen. This is how far I got already, only the variable timing cannot be fit into this way of working.
This is an implementation of the State of a StatefulWidget. This works, but all of the widgets (from (widget.sponsorWidgets) are shown the _timeoutValue amount of time, while I want to be able to set the time for each widget individually. Kind of like a kiosk where you show some interesting stuff for 30 seconds, and then show an ad for 2 seconds, to turn back to the interesting widget for another 30 seconds.
I was trying with dart.io sleep method, or with await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1)); But I dont seem to find the right way to do this. Could anyone assit with this please.
Thanks a lot
late int _selectedListIndex;
late int _counterForNonZeroIndex;
late int _timeoutValue;
late Timer _scrollingThing;
final ItemScrollController horizontalItemScrollController =
    ItemScrollController();
final ItemPositionsListener itemPositionsListener =
    ItemPositionsListener.create();

@override
void initState() {
  _selectedListIndex = 0;
  _counterForNonZeroIndex = 1;
  _timeoutValue = 30;
  super.initState();
  startScroll();
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _scrollingThing.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}

void startScroll() {
  // Autoscrolling listview code
  if (horizontalItemScrollController.isAttached) {
    horizontalItemScrollController.scrollTo(
        index: _selectedListIndex,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.
easeInOutCubic
);
    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }
  }
  if (mounted) {
    // For changing the list item that is currently scrolled to
    _scrollingThing =
        Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: _timeoutValue), (Timer t) {
      if (_selectedListIndex == 0) {
        _counterForNonZeroIndex += 1;
        if (_counterForNonZeroIndex >= widget.sponsorWidgets.length) {
          _counterForNonZeroIndex = 1;
        }
        _selectedListIndex = _counterForNonZeroIndex;
      } else {
        _timeoutValue = 5;
        _selectedListIndex = 0;
      }

      setState(() {
        horizontalItemScrollController.jumpTo(
          index: _selectedListIndex,
        );
      });
    });
  }
}
``


With the help from some other user, I got to this solution. Thanks and all credit to u/Legion_A
late int _selectedListIndex;
  late Timer _scrollingTimer;
  final ItemScrollController horizontalItemScrollController =
  ItemScrollController();
  final ItemPositionsListener itemPositionsListener =
  ItemPositionsListener.create();


  @override
  void initState() {
    _selectedListIndex = 0;
    super.initState();
    startScroll();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollingTimer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void startScroll() {
    if (horizontalItemScrollController.isAttached) {
      _scrollToCurrentIndex();
    }
    if (mounted) {
      _scheduleNextScroll();
    }
  }

  void _scheduleNextScroll() {
    if (mounted) {
      // grab the duration from the widget
      final currentWidget = widget.sponsorWidgets[_selectedListIndex];

      // here, if you decided to go with int as the duration type in the widget
      // you could do 
      // Timer(Duration(seconds: currentWidget.duration), () {...})
      _scrollingTimer = Timer(currentWidget.duration, () {
        setState(() {
          _selectedListIndex = (_selectedListIndex + 1) % widget.sponsorWidgets.length;
          _scrollToCurrentIndex();
        });
        _scheduleNextScroll();  // Reschedule for the next widget
      });
    }
  }

  void _scrollToCurrentIndex() {
    horizontalItemScrollController.scrollTo(
      index: _selectedListIndex,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic,
    );
  }

